# exception has been caught while processing the refactoring 'Delete Resource' in grails

Tags: grails

I always receive this weird Re-factoring error whenever i tried to delete the grails project in GGTS as well as in my grails work-space simultaneously, and I have no idea what to make of it

Dialogue box shows following statements like:
An exception has been caught while processing the re-factoring 'Delete Resource'

Reason:
Problem encountered while deleting resources.

And when i click the details button it shows "could not delete 'project name/lib' " and "could not delete 'C:\grails workspace\project name' ", can anyone suggest me a solution for this error

Answer (score 0):

It seems that your project is in use when you try to delete it. Delete first the folder with GGTS closed and then open the IDE and delete the reference.

Comment: yeah, this is what i'm doing now, but want it be more simple, i want to delete project in GGTS as well as in my grails work-space without closing the IDE, is there is any-other possibility of doing that, thanks for your reply

Comment: You have some jar in your lib folder? We need to figure out why your lib folder is in use when you try to delete the project.

Answer (score 0):

You could be right operating system permissions is too low, working in the exclipse disk, right-click properties - Safety - Edit - to improve their own power to completely control   OK